# AlertDialog doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case IDD_COLOR:
            return new AlertDialog(this); // The constructor AlertDialog(context) is not visible
    }

    return null;
}
```

Why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor [`AlertDialog(Context context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#AlertDialog%28android.content.Context%29) is `protected`, and is only visible to its class, sub-classes and classes within the same package.

See this link for how to create an `AlertDialog`:

- [Creating an AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create an `AlertDialog` as it has a protected constructor, you can make `AlertDialog`'s by using `AlertDialog.Builder`.

[More information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) on that subject.

Answer (score 1):

please use `AlertDialog.Builder`, like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(a)
        .setCustomTitle(buildAlertTitle(a, title, 18))
        .setMultiChoiceItems(choices, checkedChoices, multiChoiceClickListener)
        .setPositiveButton(okButtonLabel, okButtonClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton(cancelButtonLabel, cancelButtonClickListener);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); // create one

alert.show(); //display it
```

For more information, please use Google "android AlertDialog.Builder sample"
BR
shawn